# Can anyone please explain this python syntax - reverse word

Tags: python, reverse

Could anyone please explain what is, `message = " "` and `for b in variable: message = b+message?`

```
variable = raw_input("Input a word to reverse: ")
message = ""
for b in variable:
    message = b+message
print (message)
```

Thank you

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your message. I understand that when you enter any word, lets say "Hello", it will reverse word to "olleh". You are using a For loop to iterate over a given sequence.I did not understand why message = b+message, how does this message = b+message converts to "olleh"

Comment: lets say the word is "hello", so the `variable` is "hello", and `b` each equals `h` `e` `l` `l` `o`, then the message will be `h` `eh` `leh` `lleh` `olleh`, so you see, it reverse the word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
variable = raw_input("Input a word to reverse: ")
message = ""
for b in variable:
    message = b+message
print (message)
```

Example : Input a word to reverse:

"Hello"

for loop : Iteration by iteration

1. b="H" in variable
   message = H+""="H"
2. b="e" in variable

message = e+"H"="eH"

3. b="l" in variable

message = l+"eH"="leH"

4. b="l" in variable

message = l+"eH"="lleH"

5. b="o" in variable

message = l+"eH"="olleH"

Hope this helps you with clear understanding.

Comment: @nature7 please Mark answer so that Question can be closed and will help others with same question.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy. This is basic stuff... You should probably look into some Python tutorials...

```
message = ""
```

Is assigning an empty string to a variable

```
for b in variable:
```

Is a construct that will step through each item in variable and within the following block you can access that item via b.  So in this case variable is a string and this will step through each letter of the string

```
message = b+message
```

Is taking the letter as mentioned above, and pretending it to the existing message and then assigning that back to message.  So if message was 'eh' and the next letter was 'l'. Then message would now equal 'leh'

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please do understand that, some people on this forum are from biology background, like me. Sometimes just reading will not help. So we have to ask some one to explain in a non-programming way.

Comment: @nature7 did not mean to sound mean, but Really though, you should look into tutorials online. I'm sure there are interactive ones online that can teach you this basic stuff.  Way better than reading from a book or seeing an example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advice though.